# Cardinality of the class of real nullsets?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

How do I prove that the class of Lebesgue measure zero sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ has cardinality $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the power of the continuum? (I wan't to do this also for meager sets but hopefully I will deduce it from the first answer. It should be more less the same). I have the impression it is a trivial observation which I am currently missing. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need the observation that there is *one* set of size continuum and Lebesgue measure zero, as the Lebesgue null sets are closed under subsets (in fact, they form an [ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28set_theory%29)). The typical example is Cantor's middle third set $C$. Any subset of it is also of measure zero, and there are $2^{|C|}=2^{\mathfrak c}$ such subsets.

For meager, the argument is very similar; again, you just need that there is a meager set of size continuum. Actually, the Cantor set works here as well.

Answer (score 4):

All subsets of the Cantor set have measure zero (and are meager); the Cantor set has cardinality $\mathfrak c$, so it has $2^{\mathfrak c}$ subsets.

Comment: It was easy indeed. Thanks!